# PhotoView Windows 7 Reference Application

Tags: windows, windows-7

I downloaded the [PhotoView reference app](http://uachelpers.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29976) for Win7 with source.  The app works, but I can't get the project to build.

There is a ServiceControlInterop C++ project in the solution that won't build.  I figured out that it needed the Win7 SDK, which I downloaded, but now that I've got the proper winsvc.h referenced I get a slew of new errors.  I'm far from an adept C++ developer, so I'm hoping this list will call out something obvious to some C++ guru:

UPDATE: anelson was exactly correct, adding those paths allowed me to compile the ServiceControlInterop project.

For those interested, you'll also need the [UACHelpers](http://uachelpers.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29976) project and the [Microsoft.KtmIntegration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc303707(loband).aspx) class to get the whole solution to compile, it's quite a beast.  Add the UACHelpers project to the solution and create a new project for the Microsoft.KtmIntegration class (the link is to a code listing on MSDN... I think it must be a supporting class they forgot to include with the PhotoView source.)

```
Error   13  error C2065: 'NETWORK_MANAGER_FIRST_IP_ADDRESS_ARRIVAL_GUID' : undeclared identifier    C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\Winsvc.h   313 ServiceControlInterop (Windows7Plugins\TrigerStartService\ServiceControlInterop)
Error   14  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\Winsvc.h   318 ServiceControlInterop (Windows7Plugins\TrigerStartService\ServiceControlInterop)
Error   15  error C2078: too many initializers  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\Winsvc.h   318 ServiceControlInterop (Windows7Plugins\TrigerStartService\ServiceControlInterop)
Error   16  error C2065: 'NETWORK_MANAGER_LAST_IP_ADDRESS_REMOVAL_GUID' : undeclared identifier C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\Winsvc.h   321 ServiceControlInterop (Windows7Plugins\TrigerStartService\ServiceControlInterop)
Error   17  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\include\Winsvc.h   326 ServiceControlInterop (
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/XP2Win7).  You definitely need the Windows 7 SDK as you've already figured out.  But you need to have your include and lib paths set up to point to the Windows 7 SDK as well.

In Visual Studio 2k8, go to Tools | Options, and in the tree click Projects and Solutions | VC++ Directories.

Your include directories for both architectures should be:

[image: Include directories]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3427/3864518685_a0c71c4006.jpg))</sub>

Your library directories should be:

[image: Library directories]
<sub>(source: [flickr.com](https://farm4.static.flickr.com/3509/3864518701_cb0b61f786.jpg))</sub>

(NB: This is for x64.  For x86 drop the 'x64' from the end of the path

**UPDATE**: Forgot to mention you may need to do a Rebuild of the project after you change the include path, if the precompiled headers were already generated with the missing header files.

Answer (score 0):

For x64 if you downloaded the x86 install your best bet is to just do a 32 bit build. Use configuration manager to switch to x86, rebuild, all the references etc that you need are there. No jumping through hoops to find KtmIntegration, UacHelper and the like. You probably do need the SDK and to have integrated it to VS - either as described in the other answer or by using the tool you can reach from the Start menu. (I had the SDK already and had integrated it, so I can't prove it wouldn't work without it, but the documentation says you need it to compile the C++ parts.)

If you don't mind re-downloading, an updated version was released Jan 27 - http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/XP2Win7/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2977. No SQL dependency, plus both an x86 and x64 install.

Kate